# discord.py message.channel.send not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I am making a blackjack game using [discord.py](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), I am changing the value of Ace from 11 to 1 instead but no message is being sent to the channel and I am not getting any errors.

```py
def ask_A(self):
    num_A = []
    for c in range(0, len(self.deck)):
        if self.deck[c].get_value() == "A" and self.deck[c].get_points() == 11:
            num_A.append(c)

    for i in num_A:
        message.channel.send(
            "Your current cards are " + str(self.print_cards()) + ", Total is " + str(self.sum_cards()) + "\n")
        self.deck[i].change_points(1)
        message.channel.send("Changed value of Ace to prevent loss")
        message.channel.send("Your cards are " + str(self.print_cards()) + ", Total is " + str(self.sum_cards()) + "\n")
```

Comment: Are you sure you are appending entries into `num_A` (have you verified with print statements or similar)?

Comment: There are no entries. Previously I made it so that the system prints into the console whether or not to switch the value of Ace. That was dumb because everyone will switch to Ace to prevent loss.

Comment: I made it an async method and await message.channel.send everything I wanted to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're forgetting to `await` your statements. Anything in the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client) that is a coroutine needs to have `await` expression.

## Example:

```py
await message.channel.send("Hello! This is my message")
```

Read up about Async IO [here](https://realpython.com/async-io-python/).